# Navigation Bar moves text in Text View down by 2x its height

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

I'm trying to create a simple View Controller, containing only a Text View. This view has an associated Navigation Controller that adds a Navigation Bar with "Shows Navigation Bar" disabled. The view's constraints are:

- Text View.top = Top Layout Guide.bottom
- Text View.bottom = Bottom Layout Guide.top
- Text View.leading = leadingMargin
- Text View.trailing = trailingMargin

[image: no navigation bar]

As soon as I enable the "Shows Navigation Bar" property on the Navigation Controller, the text inside the Text View slides down by the height of the Navigation Bar, while the Text View stays where it is.

[image: navigation bar enabled, frames not yet updated]

After running "Update frames" to account for the layout guide that has been moved down, the Text View has moved down by the height of the Navigation Bar, which doubles the effect on the text in the Text View.

[image: frames have been updated]

Do I do something wrong or is this a bug in UIKit? Is there a simple workaround?

I'm using XCode 7.1 (7B91b) and iOS 9.1.

Comment: What is happening in running app?

Comment: In the running app, the same thing happens as in Interface Builder (tested both on a device and the simulator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uncheck "Adjust Scroll View Insets" for the viewcontroller in the Attributes inspector!

[image: View Controller]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm.

Comment: Make sure that you check the boxes under "Extend Edges"